# Create a custom tile list in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I need to create a tile list that looks like the image below. It contains the button at the end of the tile list and it should be inside the scroll bar. I tried extending the existing TileList with no luck.

[image]

sample code

```
public class CustomTileList extends TileList {  

        public function CustomTileList()
        {
            super();            

        }

        protected var _button : Button ;

        public function get button ( ) : Button {
            return this._button ;
        }

        public function set button ( value : Button ) : void {
            this._button = value;
        }       

        override protected function createChildren():void
        {           
            super.createChildren();
            _button = new Button ();
            _button .label = "More";

            this.addChildAt( _button , super.numChildren - 1 );

        } 

    }
```

Comment: The answer is to extend the list.  What have you tried?  I expect this to be rather difficult.  Are you using spark components?  Or MX Components?  Which version of Flex are you using?  Can you share some code?

Comment: added the code what i tried. i'm new to as3 i don't know my approach is correct or not. Need a solution soon....

Comment: How about creating an HGroup with the TileList and the Button in it. If you wrap the group in a Scroller, you should be close to what you need. I would personally not extend the TileList. This is much more a composition of components.

Comment: In addition to what @ChristopheHerreman suggested (which I think is the quickest solution), you'd have to force the TileList to render all of its items or you'll get a scrollbar in a scrollbar. This means you'll have to bind `requestedRowCount` to the number of items divided by the number of columns. Bear in mind that you'll loose layout virtualization, so I would look for another solution if there's a whole lot of items.

Comment: @ChristopheHerreman With a Spark List using TileLayout and a custom skin it should be easy to set something up like this, using an approach similar to what you describe in the skin.  But, I see nothing wrong w/ extending the list to add the new button as a skin part. I'm not sure why you'd push against extending the component.

Comment: @Reboog711 The inheritance approach will most likely work as well, but in my personal experience it is harder and will lead to more unwanted side effects than composition.

Comment: @ChristopheHerreman I do not understand how do one w/o the other.  I see no way to add a button other than composition.  I see no way to create a UI Flex component without inheritance.  In your sample; you are inheriting from an HGroup; and adding a button via composition.

Comment: guys i'm using AS3. So I think I can't use the HGroup there. Can you guys suggest me another approach.

Comment: @BPSK see this **[LINK](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108036807/ExTitleListExt.swf)** maybe will be useful. is this what you need?

Comment: @GastonF. something similar to your example. i have item render for tiles and at the end of the tiles need a button. how did you do that in r example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In following Christophe Herreman's approach, If you need to achieve this in Flex 3 you will have to use a Canvas as the container and set the correct scroll policies. See below example

```
<mx:Canvas horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="auto" height="300">
    <mx:TileList id="tileList" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off" columnCount="2">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <mx:VBox width="100" height="100" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center">
                    <mx:Label text="{data}" />
                </mx:VBox>
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:dataProvider>
            <mx:ArrayCollection>
                <mx:String>Tile 1</mx:String>
                <mx:String>Tile 2</mx:String>
                <mx:String>Tile 3</mx:String>
                <mx:String>Tile 4</mx:String>
                <mx:String>Tile 5</mx:String>
                <mx:String>Tile 6</mx:String>
                <mx:String>Tile 7</mx:String>
                <mx:String>Tile 8</mx:String>
            </mx:ArrayCollection>
        </mx:dataProvider>
    </mx:TileList>
    <mx:Button id="button" label="Button" />
</mx:Canvas>
```

This is not going to suffice for the following reasons

- The `tileList` has to scale to the height of all items so that all items are visible.
- Canvas places objects in absolute position so you need to place the `button` properly.

Considering the fact the container can scale and the fact that `tileList` may include more items these changes can be done in the `updateDisplayList` function as shown below.

```
override protected function updateDisplayList( unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number ):void {
    super.updateDisplayList( unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight );

    tileList.height = tileList.rowHeight * Math.ceil( tileList.dataProvider.length / tileList.columnCount );
    button.y = tileList.height;
    button.x = (tileList.width / 2) - (button.width / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Christophe Herreman said, I would recommand you to put a Hgroup into the scroller, into this Hgroup, you put your tileList and the button.

Here is some sample code:

```
<s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:HGroup>
        <s:TileGroup requestedColumnCount="2" requestedRowCount="2">
            <s:Button />
            <s:Button />
            <s:Button />
            <s:Button />
        </s:TileGroup>
        <s:Button label="Button" />
    </s:HGroup>
</s:Scroller>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using AS3, there i can't find HGroup.

Comment: HGroup is a spark component, available with Flex 4 (see [doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/HGroup.html)). What version of Flex are you using ?

Comment: Flex 3.2 was released in 2008 (not sure). That's pretty old. Are you able to migrate your application to a current version of flex ? Because it will be hard with the few components available in Flex 3.2

Answer (score 0):

Here the code of link I was send, maybe will be useful:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            public function init():void{
                var arr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
                arr.addItem(new Object());
                arr.addItem(new Object());
                arr.addItem(new Object());
                arr.addItem(new Object());
                arr.addItem(new Object());
                arr.addItem(new Object());
                tl.dataProvider = arr;
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:TileList id="tl" allowMultipleSelection="true" columnCount="1" verticalScrollPolicy="on">             
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>                       
                <mx:VBox height="100%" width="100%" borderStyle="solid" horizontalAlign="center">
                    <mx:Grid id="myGrid">
                        <mx:GridRow id="row1">
                            <mx:GridItem>
                                <mx:Button label="Button 1"/>
                            </mx:GridItem>
                            <mx:GridItem>
                                <mx:Button label="Button 2"/>
                            </mx:GridItem>
                        </mx:GridRow>
                        <mx:GridRow id="row2">
                            <mx:GridItem>
                                <mx:Button label="Button 3"/>
                            </mx:GridItem>
                            <mx:GridItem>
                                <mx:Button label="Button 4"/>
                            </mx:GridItem>
                        </mx:GridRow>                   
                    </mx:Grid>      
                    <mx:Button label="Button 5"/>
                </mx:VBox>
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:TileList>
</mx:Application>
```

In this **[link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108036807/ExTitleListExt.swf)** you can try this.

**Note:** This is an basic example for to show how the itemrenderer works, but maybe will be better that you have a itemrenderer in another component.
Please see this links for more explanation:

1. [Link 1](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.html)
2. [Link 2](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt2.html)